# Number of connected bipartite graphs with maximum possible degree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Is there a formula which gives the number of connected bipartite graphs with $n$ vertices such that the degree of every vertex is at most $d$?  I can determine the results computationally using [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/), but it would be nice if there were a published formula I could use and cite instead.

Hanlon [1] gives formulas for determining the number of connected bipartite graphs by order, but not for capping the results to a maximum degree.

[1] Phil Hanlon. [The enumeration of bipartite graphs.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X79901845) *Discrete Mathematics* 28, 1979, pp. 49–57.

Comment: Are your graphs labelled?

Comment: No, they're unlabelled, as in Hanlon's Table 1 ([OEIS A005142](http://oeis.org/A005142)).